# Loading code from a TXT file on Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is there a way to load external code from a .txt file on action script 3? I'd like to put some addChild() codes inside a .txt file to execute on Flash then, for example:

**file.txt content**

```
addChild(mc1);
addChild(mc2);
```

My application does something like this:

```
fileContents = URLRequest(file.txt);
```

Now, fileContents has 2 lines of codes I wanna run on Flash, how to run these?

Thanks

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513048/executing-as3-code-from-a-string you cannot evaluate a string into runnable code. You'd have to create your own interpreter

Comment: **SWF** applications contain compiled version of source **ActionScript3** (so called **ABC**-code), so no, it is not possible to run additional un-compiled **ActionScript3** instructions with your applications. If you believe that it is exactly what you want, your best choice here (I think) is to use some kind of (**XML**- or **JSON**-based) mock language with a simple interpreter to execute its instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Any chance to at least make the addChild code recognize what's inside the .txt file? Example: addChild(fileContents) ?

Comment: `addChild` only refers to `DisplayObject` instances and child instances, not the raw string from the `fileContents`. If you want to display the text on the screen you'll first have to create a `TextField` (let's say it's named `contentTextField`) and then use `addChild(contentTextField)`

Comment: No, I was more talking about the .txt file carrying the name of a movie clip I want to add, so, addChild(fileContents), if I put mc1 inside the .txt file, my Flash will add the movie clip mc1 on my library. I remember in AS 2, this was possible with MovieClip["customName"] something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function that re-creates the txt files's code dynamically inside AS3.

**(1)** Extract the code lines into some array of Strings.

**(2)** Make a function to extract each line into parts. 
(*eg:* extract the command `addChild` and parameter `mc1`).

**(3)** Make a `function run_Code` where you use the command and parameter.

Example code without array, just a string value, for simplicity...

```
var myStr = "addChild(mc1);"; //# you read this value from txt file

//# extract using length ( substr )
var myCmd = myStr.substr( 0, myStr.indexOf( "(" ) ); //extract "addChild" (eg: from start until first bracket)

//# extract using positions ( substring ) 
var myParam = myStr.substring( myStr.indexOf("(") +1 ,  myStr.indexOf(")")  ); 

trace( "Command is: " + myCmd + " ... Param is: " + myParam );

run_Code( myCmd, myParam );

function run_Code ( in_command:String , in_param:String  ) :void
{
    //# handle possible commands
    if ( in_command == "addChild" ) { stage.addChild( this[ in_param ] ); }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this no doubt will help me a lot!